# How to add Google translate box (single word/sentence, not whole page) to website?

Tags: jquery, google-translate

How to add Google translate box (single word/sentence, not whole page) to website like https://translate.google.com/

Comment: Hi! As a question, this is really too broad. When coming to Stack, try to fix your own issue and come with a question like "using this tool, I have this code and trying to do X, but it returns me with Y instead". I'd say you can start by looking into the Translate API to do what you want: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Not exact like Google providing. Please improve answer if you have the better solution.

```
<div class="translate">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="input_element" id="target" placeholder="Type Germen word"> 
        </form>
        <br>
        <div class="inpt-el"></div><br>
        <div class="translate_control" lang="de"></div>
    </div>   

 <script>
    function googleSectionalElementInit() {
      new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
        background: '#f4fa58'
      }, 'google_sectional_element');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
      $('.inpt-el').text($(this).val());
    });
    </script>
```